# Can typescript infer nested values from a function argument?

Tags: typescript

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=85&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwSA7gUwCYBU4CcDmaUEMAvDAN4CwAUAJACCAXDABQUAWAlgwL4uceLaLi5h8vAJSkAfBV4AaWnQBCLdtxX9KmlmACuAWwBGaXFNnylNXrVpQAngAc0MBklSYsZGACIGvjAAPn4qvnY0ji5uBBAA8gBmADzeaAAeUGhgGCTuyOjYMj4ACnhwhkRmEElRaCAJ8B4FOAREEADaWAC6Mu0ADF0RtTAthFApMOmZ2blNXkXkFFB4YyxYCvCxLAyxiSlFtjT2zq6jRADC4MtiZhNTWTluc4U+AEpooLgYSSJi+BtncZYGQyIYnGAAWQcADEwD47hkHrN8vNWCs+msVhcrnAbrh9pIyEUAG4gLgYCKgSCwQwwsAsKGwnysaRyQ60AD0HM2+BIeFccBg+jAXHAMHqjQQMCcIAgEC4xgQAtitFpsPYvm4AQEy1aUBY-l8GxWEAEWoNvl4ij8ml8Oqx+tCRp5pp0Qj8lqtkiAA)

I want to switch which args are passed, based on on the target. It seems like typescript can't infer what is passed in the function argument. Is there a way to help it figure out / write it differently so that it can infer it ?

Currently it is making a union out of all the passed arguments, but I would like it to pick out the correct argument.

```
const allowedTargets = {
    A: ({hiA}: {hiA: string})=>{},
    B: ({hiB}: {hiB: number})=>{},
}

type AllowedT = "A" | "B"

type ArgsOf<T extends AllowedT> = Parameters<typeof allowedTargets[T]>[0]

type Target<T extends AllowedT> = {target: T, args: ArgsOf<T> }

type TargetContainer<T extends AllowedT> = Record<string, Target<T>>

type MyFn = <T extends AllowedT>(arg0: TargetContainer<T>) => void

const myFn: MyFn = ()=>{}

// args are a union of all possible args
myFn({"hiA": {target: "A", args: {hiA: ""}}, "hiB": {target: "B", args: {hiA: ""}}})
```

Comment: There's quite a bunch of type definitions here, so I wonder if this is really a [mre] or if you could simplify it.  In any case, maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrK10m) meets your needs?  In your original definition there isn't anything better than `"A" | "B"` to be inferred; the problem is that `TargetContainer<"A" | "B">` doesn't properly distribute the union over the `Target` operation.

Comment: Once I try to simplify this it looks like generics are there without being needed.  Would [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9yk9N) work for you? If so I can write up an answer.  If not, let me know what I'm missing.